# Using Html.DropDownList over a SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I have the following code inside my model class :-

```
public class PageOptions
    {
        public PageOptions()
    {
      int  size = Int32.Parse(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TechPageSize"]);
            NameSelectionOptions = new SelectList(
            new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem { Text=size.ToString(), Value = size.ToString()},
            new SelectListItem { Text="50", Value = "50"}, 
            new SelectListItem { Text="100", Value = "100"},
            new SelectListItem { Text="200", Value = "200"},
            new SelectListItem { Text="500", Value = "500"}
        }, "Value", "Text");

    }

    public SelectList NameSelectionOptions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but how i can display the SelectList inside a Html.DropDownList ? and setting the default valueto be size?
Thanks

Comment: After 3 years, are you happy with the answer yet? :)

Comment: Heading into 5th year now... are you happy yet? :)

Answer (score 5):

You simply pass the desired selection as a 4th parameter to the `SelectList` constructor:

```
NameSelectionOptions = new SelectList(
    new List<SelectListItem> {
    new SelectListItem { Text=size.ToString(), Value = size.ToString()},
    new SelectListItem { Text="50", Value = "50"}, 
    new SelectListItem { Text="100", Value = "100"},
    new SelectListItem { Text="200", Value = "200"},
    new SelectListItem { Text="500", Value = "500"}
}, "Value", "Text", size);   // <<< Add size here
```

This is far more flexible than selecting a specific item in the list.

There are several options for binding a list to the view. You can use a property in the ViewModel, however standard practice (as per Microsoft's scaffolding templates) is to pass dropdown lists to a view in a ViewBag entry *of the same name as the Model property*. This has the added bonus of automatically binding the simpler `@Html.DropDownList("Size")` version to both a Model property called `Size` and the list in `ViewBag.Size`.

e.g.

### In Controller:

```
ViewBag.Size = new SelectList(
    new List<SelectListItem> {
    new SelectListItem { Text=size.ToString(), Value = size.ToString()},
    new SelectListItem { Text="50", Value = "50"}, 
    new SelectListItem { Text="100", Value = "100"},
    new SelectListItem { Text="200", Value = "200"},
    new SelectListItem { Text="500", Value = "500"}
}, "Value", "Text", size);   // <<< Add size here
viewModel.Size = size;
return View(viewModel);
```

Where viewModel contains any properties you want edited (including `Size`).

### In View:

```
   @Html.DropDownList("Size")
```

or if you prefer the strongly typed version.

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Size, (SelectList)ViewBag.Size)
```

In any case the consistent naming will help avoid problems.

Default values can go in the ViewBag, but the selection should be bound to your ViewModel so you can use the same ViewModel to receive the posted back values.

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Size, (SelectList)ViewBag.Size, ViewBag.DefaultSize)
```

### Update:

If you do not wish to bind the current value to anything (as per comment), you simply need to have the `ViewBag.Size` set to you `SelectList` by the controller and have this is the View. You do not need a value in the Model.

```
   @Html.DropDownList("Size")
```

The default selection will be the selection (4th parameter, size) in `new SelectList()` above.

Comment: ok but i do not want to bind the size in any mean , as this drop-down list is used for filtering purposes , where the user will be selecting the number of records page page. so i need to use Html.DropDownList instead of Html.DropDownListFor. but i can not pass three parameters to the Html.SropdownList !!

Comment: and also my current view is using the IPagedList<> which does not contain anHtml.DropdownList

Comment: You do not *need* to supply a bound value. Simply having @Html.DropDownList("Size") is enough to put the list on the page with the default selected size.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add **Selected** property in it:

```
new SelectListItem { Text=size.ToString(), 
                     Value = size.ToString(),
                     Selected = true}
```

**Model:**

```
public class PageOptions
    {
        public PageOptions()
    {
      int  size = Int32.Parse("20");
            NameSelectionOptions = new SelectList(
            new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem { Text=size.ToString(), Value = size.ToString()},
            new SelectListItem { Text="50", Value = "50"}, 
            new SelectListItem { Text="100", Value = "100"},
            new SelectListItem { Text="200", Value = "200"},
            new SelectListItem { Text="500", Value = "500"}
        }, "Value", "Text");

    }

    public SelectList NameSelectionOptions { get; set; }
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    }
```

**Action:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            PageOptions model = new PageOptions();

            return View(model);
        }
```

**Strongly Typed View:**

```
@model TestAjaxUpload.Models.PageOptions
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedValue,Model.NameSelectionOptions)
```

if you want to do without changing your current model for view then, create instance inside view and pass like this:

```
@model SomeModelClass
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@{

    TestAjaxUpload.Models.PageOptions objModel = new TestAjaxUpload.Models.PageOptions();

}


@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedValue,objModel.NameSelectionOptions)
```

but you should add **PageOptions** `SelectList` as **property** in your **Model** and use it, i don't recommend to do directly in **View**.

**Update (Using ViewBag):**

with ViewBag you can do this way:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {

            PageOptions model = new PageOptions();

            ViewBag.List = model.NameSelectionOptions;
            ViewBag.Selected = "20";

            return View(model);
        }
```

in View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedValue,ViewBag.List as SelectList,ViewBag.Selected as string)
```

Comment: but how i can referecne the selectList inside my DropDownlist, without using viewBag ?

Comment: do you have any model binded with view?

Comment: i do want to have the  PageOptions part of any model, as it only contains static values ,, so i need to directly reference the PageOption SelectList insdie my view?

Comment: see the updated answer, hope it helps, any question you can ask me

Comment: i want to be doing this using viewBag and set the defualt value to be equal to antoher viewbag something such as @Html.DropDownList(ViewBag.PageOptions,"Text","Value",ViewBag.current)

Comment: you can do that way as well but what i understood you want to do without using viewbag

Comment: you have to set value in viewbag selected and just pass ot on DropDownList for to make it selected

Comment: this what i am trying to do how to build the DropDownList with viewbag to set its value and another viewbag to select the defualt value ?

Comment: the problem i am now facing is that my view uses IPagedList<Model>, which does not allow to define Html.DropDownList inside it ??

Comment: Whatever the model of view is html helper methods are always accessible in view