# Populating dropdown list returning null pointer exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, drop-down-menu, razor-pages

A small project consisting of 2 classes `Appointments` and `Department`, I need to be able to select the department name from a dropdown box.

I have tried `<select>` and `asp-items`, both are returning `nullpointerexcpetion` or something similar like `ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')`

```
Appointment Class

    public class Appointment
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
 
        [Display(Name = "Department")]

        public virtual int Dep_Id { get; set; }

        public Department Departments{ get; set; }

    }
```

```
Department class
    public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Two controllers using Entity Framework (Web API and MVC) were scaffolded based on these classes and localdb `Department` table was filled with some values.
In the MVC controller generated from `Appointment`, I created a method

```
        public void PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList()
        {
            var departmentsQuery = from d in _context.Departments
                                   orderby d.Name
                                   select d;
            ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(departmentsQuery.AsNoTracking(), "ID", "Name");
        }
```

And finally in the `Create.cshtml` also generated from `Appointment`, these attempts do not work.

`<select asp-for="Dep_Id" class="control-label" asp-items=ViewBag.DepartmentID></select>`

generates an empty dropdown
and

`@Html.DropDownList("dep", new SelectList(ViewBag.DepartmentID, "ID", "Name"))`
crashes the page.

I am not sticking to any method, any solution that works based on any controller is fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think you are missing to convert variable to List**

> In the controller:

```
var departmentsQuery = from d in _context.Departments
                                   orderby d.Name
                                   select d;
    List<Department> department = departmentsQuery.ToList();
    
    ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(department, "ID", "Name");
```

> In the View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DepartmentID, null, new { @class ="form-control" })
```

**or you can replace the "null" with whatever you want display as default selector, i.e. "Select Department".**

Answer (score 0):

I think you lack typecasting like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494316/using-html-dropdownlist-over-a-selectlist) question. I can not test it now, but i think this is the solution.
`@Html.DropDownListFor("dep", ViewBag.DepartmentID as SelectList)`